# CSS Vertical Stack

Tags: css, layout, html

I currently have a bunch of `inline-block` `div`s stacked up horizontally. When the container is full, they spill over nicely into the next row:
[image]

Is it possible to do the same thing vertically, without changing the HTML?
[image]

To generate this picture, I had to move each column into a container `div`. I can't modify the source HTML, so this isn't an option.

[CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/KL3n8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CSS2**
Alas, to my knowledge this is not possible with pure CSS and HTML. I do know there is a jQuery plugin [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) that does this quite nicely though.

**CSS3**
Using [CSS3's Multi-column Layout Mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) you can achieve the question's layout (though it won't have as many options as abovementioned masonry). IE support is from 10 and up I think, and you may need some browser prefixes. The non-prefixed version would look something like this (on your container):

```
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
width: 480px;
```

The above was adapted from [this blogpost](http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/) that links to [this demo](http://sickdesigner.com/demo/css-masonry/css-masonry.html) (though there [are others](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/) too).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on browser support you could use `column-count`.